# Get first value by ID and index

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this data frame and I want to group by ID and create two new columns which take the values for each row within an ID group.

```
id <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
x <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
y <- c(10, 25, 35, 15, 25, 10)

df <- cbind(id, x, y)
df
```

I just want to get two new columns which show all of the values for `y` for each `x` within an ID group. So `x` is the index and the two new columns would be first and second `y` value for each `ID` like the below:

```
id <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
x <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
y <- c(10, 25, 35, 15, 25, 10)
first <- c(10, 10, 35, 35, 25, 25)
second <- c(25, 25, 15, 15, 10, 10)

df <- cbind(id, x, y, first, second)
df
```

I was thinking something like:

```
df <- df %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(first = ...?)
```

Comment: You should be able to do something like `merge(df, reshape(df, direction = "wide", timevar = "x", idvar = "id"))` (but ensure the input is a data frame - using `cbind()` on vectors returns a matrix, not a data frame).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just have two values, then you can use `first` and `last`.

```
library(dplyr)

df_final <- as.data.frame(df) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(id) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(x, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(first = dplyr::first(y),
                second = dplyr::last(y))
```

The only reason for using `as.data.frame()` above was that your sample data returned a matrix.

Comment: Thanks that works except if the data frame is not ordered by the `x` column it wont work. Try replacing the x vector with x <- c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2). If you stick in a df <- df[order(df$id, df$x),] before the line you wrote it works just fine.

Comment: I've worked the sorting into the pipeline now with `arrange`.